# how to install apache tomcat service on windows server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, tomcat6

I'm attempting to install apache-tomcat-6.0.20.exe on windows server 2012 R2. It is being installed on a default amazon aws windows server 2012 R2 image.
I am using jre version jdk-6u17-windows-i586.exe.
Yes, these are old installs. But the app I am using requires them.

Step 1: install jdk-6u17-windows-i586.exe.

Step 2: install apache-tomcat-6.0.20.exe. Use all default settings.

Expected: it installs.

Actual: Failed to install Tomcat6 service. Check your settings and permissions. Ignore and continue anyway?

[image]

I am a newbie with windows server 2012 R2. Can anyone help me to install the service?

Update: I found Tomcat 6.0 logs file. One of them named jakarta_service_20160329.log contains the following entries:

```
[2016-03-29 02:42:56] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2016-03-29 02:42:56] [info] Running Service...
[2016-03-29 02:42:56] [info] Starting service...
[2016-03-29 02:42:56] [174  javajni.c] [error] The specified module could not be found.
[2016-03-29 02:42:56] [994  prunsrv.c] [error] Failed creating java C:\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
[2016-03-29 02:42:56] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 1
[2016-03-29 02:42:56] [info] Run service finished.
[2016-03-29 02:42:56] [info] Procrun finished.
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Follow all four steps here: http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-error-prunsrvc-failed-creating-java-jvmdll/

Solution

```
1) Copy msvcr71.dll from java’s bin directory to tomcat’s bin folder.
2) Add java’s bin directory to windows environment variable.
3) Copy msvcr71.dll from java’s bin directory to windows\system32 folder.
4) Make sure your tomcat’s pointing to correct jvm.dll folder.
```